# Linked-List: How to reduce execution time?

Tags: java, linked-list, runtime

I am making a word suggestion program where a user enters a word and I display relevant next words. I am generating the words from a novel, first I delete words that do not add much meaning, then I insert pair of words into a linked list and give them an `order` of how many time they appear. If there is a duplicate pair of word, I increase the `order` and skip over them. My biggest issue is time complexity, I have already managed to cut running time from 30 minutes to 12 minutes with a 3MB .txt file, but I want to go further. From my understanding `if(myList.contains(prevWord, currWord));` is taking the most time.

```java
while(stopScan.hasNext()) {
     stopWord.add(stopScan.next());
}
String prevWord = textScan.next().toLowerCase().replaceAll("[^a-z ]", ""), currWord = "";
while(textScan.hasNext()) {
     while(stopWord.contains(prevWord)) {
          prevWord = textScan.next().toLowerCase().replaceAll("[^a-z ]", "");
     }
     currWord = textScan.next().toLowerCase().replaceAll("[^a-z ]", "");
     while(stopWord.contains(currWord)) {
          currWord = textScan.next().toLowerCase().replaceAll("[^a-z ]", "");
     }
     if(myList.contains(prevWord, currWord));
     else myList.insertTail(prevWord, currWord);
     prevWord = currWord;
}
myList.sort();
```

```java
boolean contains(T wordOne, T wordTwo) {
     Node<T> temp = head;
     while(temp != null) {
          if(temp.wordOne.equals(wordOne) && temp.wordTwo.equals(wordTwo)) {
               temp.order++;
               return true;
          }
          temp = temp.next;
     }
     return false;
}
```

```java
void sort() {
     Node<T> temp = head;
     while(temp!=null) {
          if(temp.prev!=null && temp.order>temp.prev.order) {
               swap(temp, temp.prev);
               temp = temp.prev;
          }
          else temp = temp.next;
        }
    }
```

Also, I am implementing my own linked list except for storing words that do not add much meaning. I understand that linked list is not the best way to go, but it is my only choice. Thankyou!

Comment: "Can you optimize this code, except, you can't change anything". Obviously, there is possible way to answer this question. You can make this process the file in a few milliseconds, _if_ we can get rid of the silly data structure usage here. Why do you say _ I understand that linked list is not the best way to go, but it is my only choice._ ? This question needs way more context. If it was just: I want this, but faster - easy. But it's some weird mix of: "I want this, but faster, but there are nebulously stated bizarro requirements".

Comment: Because my assignment is to use linked list, I just want to go above and beyond.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

The obv. part is to use a Map for this problem. Its made for this.

If you really only are able to use a LinkedList, you could sort the input values and then you can just iterate over the list a single time and count these words until you get a different word:

input:

B A F O B O R B

sort:

A B B B F R O O

iterating and counting:

A=1 B=3 F=1 R=1 O=2